# Install Mac OS Lion on Macbook with existing Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot

Tags: 12.04, macbook, macosx, refit

I don't usually create my own questions, because I can find what I need through other people's questions. However, this one doesn't seem to be anywhere, except in one place where someone is talking about not using Apple hardware. So here it goes. I am using Apple hardware. I have a MacBook 1,1 with Intel Core2Duo running Ubuntu Precise Pangolin flawlessly. I never considered starting with Mac OSx and dual-booting because I never liked Mac OS. Now that I'm realizing that the only way I'm going to be able to run my DAW (Reaper) nicely and use a Firewire recording interface is to run Mac OSx, I'm considering it again. I want to go the opposite direction of most people and install Mac OSx next to an existing Ubuntu installation and have a boot menu with refit. I've installed refit in Ubuntu and I've converted the .dmg file for Mac OS Lion to a .iso file. Now, should I mount the .iso in Ubuntu and run it there, or burn a DVD and restart? I'm trying to gauge how to do this without hurting my existing Ubuntu installation. I will of course keep looking for existing answers in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. i went OSx after wasting hours just tinkering with the OS, You *can* get some Firewire audio working under linux, but when you need to get the studio set up, and people are waiting, its game over. I'm not mad keen on OSX myself, so i dual boot too. I Love linux, but its still not 100% yet, i've been involved in Linux for over 15 years. and now laptop cooling/fan control/battery life seems as flaky now as it ever was, and pulseaudio is a huge obstacle in the way to serious audio. See you on Linux sometime, *hear* you on the Mac sometime too.

Answer (score 1):

this is pretty unusual, but might work. There are some problems though. I myself never tried installing this way and i am pretty sure you will run into some problems. Almost certain you will have to reinstall grub and stuff.

Be sure to make a backup of all your important files. And i would personally consider do install Mac OS X first, then Ubuntu again. You can but the lion installation and create a spare partition for ubuntu before installing os x.

About the Lion DMG: If you have a friend with Mac OS X running, you can easily turn the dmg into a bootable usb drive or dvd. I think i followed this guide: http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive. However there a lot of them available, just try google. Mac sure your USB Drive is large enough and correctly formated (Apple HFS... you will lose all data on that drive).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dove into it yesterday and resized my Ubuntu partition with the GParted Live CD, then got grub2 playing nicely with the resized partition and the MBR again. I think the determining factor going the opposite direction will be if the OS X installation CD will allow you to use existing free space rather than the whole disk (leaving the Ubuntu partition alone). Thank you for the tip with the DMG file. I got a "buster" symbol with my converted-to-ISO burn.